# Access another GitHub account

Tags: git, github

I try to push my code to newly created GitHub repository. I used different account for this repo and after attaching my local git to remote and trying to push I get an error:

> remote: Permission to *repo* denied to *me*. fatal: unable to access
>   'https://github.com/link': The requested URL returned error: 403

This message I receive after

```
   git push --set-upstream origin master
```

I understand from this - my previously saved settings store name / pass to my previous account. Is it right? Where can I find them?

Next question - how can I solve this? Thanks

Comment: Did you add your SSH key to the new github account?

Comment: Are both accounts contributer of your repository? Maby this will help.

Comment: no, I have not done this

Comment: this is newly created account, it's not related to my previous one in any way

Comment: Are you trying to access your new repo via SSH or via HTTPS? Look at this link https://help.github.com/articles/testing-your-ssh-connection/ and this one https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/

Comment: If your're using git via https and a credential helper to store your credentials, you could find here some help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381198/remove-credentials-from-git